# how to pass callback funtion to Angular JS dirctive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a footer directive that I can pass an array of button objects to.

here is my array...

```
    $scope.buttons = [
    {
      btnLabel: "Close",
      btnClass: "btn-p2 pull-left",
      show: true,
      disabled: false,
      callback: function(){console.log('close...');},
      role: ''
    },
    {
      btnLabel: "Save",
      btnClass: "btn-p1 pull-right",
      show: true,
      disabled: true,
      callback: saveTest,
      role: ''
    }
  ];
```

I have most of it working the way I want but, having issue with passing the callback functions. I am seeing the buttons but when I click the callback functions are not getting called. Any ideas on how to pass the callback functions?

Thanks and regards, 
dj

Answer (score 0):

Because `saveTest` is not defined in your `scope`, directive doesn't have access to it. So either you have to defined them on the scope and use them there, or you can pass them as directives attributes in its own scope:

**First way**:

```
$scope.saveTest = function () {

}
```

And then you can use the parent scope in your directive:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    templateUrl: "..."
  }
})
```

By not defining the scope in directive, you are saying I want to use parent scope here.

**Second way**:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      saveTest: '&',
      close: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: "..."
  }
})
```

Now that we have defined them in the directive we have to pass them from html like this:

```
<div some-directive save-test="saveTest" close="close"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have it working for a default footer where I just need a save and close button.  I pass the save and close callbacks as attributes.  The other one I was trying to is to have a customized footer where I can pass an array of button objects and each button call their respective call back function.